# LINQ Grouping on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I like to group a collection of objects based on some of their properties.  I can group them, but after grouping them, how can I put each group of results into their own separate list so I process each list accordingly.  Here's an example of what I have thus far:

```
public class INPRKData
{
    public string rptDate { get; set; }
    public string clientNumber { get; set; }
    public string fileNumberId { get; set; }
    public string cycleType { get; set; }
    public string streamType { get; set; }
    public string branchCode { get; set; }
}
```

grouping based on three properties: clientNumber, fileNumberId and streamType...

```
var grouped =
    from d in INPRKDataCollection
    group d by new { d.clientNumber, d.fileNumberId, d.streamType };
```

Comment: Some data behind your problem showing what you mean by putting each group into its own list?

Comment: The grouping process puts each group into its own collection; that's the whole point of the grouping operation. So it's not really clear what's the trouble you're having.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<List<INPRKData>> lists = from grp in grouped
                                     select grp.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each grouping will implement `IEnumerable<INPRKData>` and iterate over the items in the group, so you can just iterate over the groups:

```
foreach(var group in grouped)
{
    var list = group.ToList();   // the items in that group
    ...
}
```